# Different Expressjs route methods calls execute the same route method, only on DigitalOcean droplet

Tags: node.js, express, digital-ocean

For reference [this repo](https://github.com/Kmelow/route-bug) contains a sample code (clone, install npm run server).

This is my server.js

```js
const express = require('express');

const app = express();

app.get('/', (req, res) => res.send('Hello World!'));
app.post('/', (req, res) => res.send('Got a POST request'));
app.put('/', (req, res) => res.send('Got a PUT request at /'));
app.delete('/', (req, res) => res.send('Got a DELETE request at /user'));

const PORT = process.env.PORT || 5000;

app.listen(PORT, () => console.log(`Listening on ${PORT}`));
```

When I run locally `npm run server` and test with Postman I get the correct strings when calling the respective method (`GET /` => `'Hello World!'`, `POST /` => `'Got a POST request'`, and so on.

Then I have a Ubuntu droplet in DigitalOcean that I:

- Created a user
- `apt-get update` and `dit-upgrade`
- Installed node `v12.16.1` with npm `6.13.4` and `git`
- Then `git clone git@github.com:Kmelow/route-bug.git` (this is repo where my code is)
- `cd`, `npm install` and `npm start`

Next, I used Postman to test using the new URL.

Then, if I do a `GET`, `POST`, `PUT`, `DELETE` or any other method I always get `Hello World!`.

I can't understand why. What I'm doing wrong?

Comment: I can think of no other possible cause besides a mis-configured nginx proxy in front of your server.

Comment: Some possibilities: [Nginx https rewrite turns POST to GET](https://serverfault.com/questions/434205/nginx-https-rewrite-turns-post-to-get) and [POST Request redirects to GET in Nginx proxy and NodeJS](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/questions/post-request-redirects-to-get-in-nginx-proxy-and-nodejs) and [Post request turns into Get request](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24028719/post-request-turns-into-get-request).