# Nodejs GET and POST mixed up in live server but working in localhost

Tags: node.js, express, post, get

I have the following APIs, in order

```
router.post('/:name/insertDesign', function(req, res) {
  console.log('[API] /insertDesign { username: ' + req.params.name + ' }');


router.get('/:name/:project', excludeSpecialRoutes, function(req, res, next) {
    result = {
      username: 'anonymous',
      project: req.params.project,
      access: 'Public',
    };
  console.log('[API] /project', result);
```

When running the post call in localhost I got the following log:

```
[API] /insertDesign { username: vc }
```

but when running it post call in the live server the log is as follow:

```
[API] /project { username: 'anonymous',
  project: 'insertDesign',
  access: 'Public' }
```

This is very confusing, shouldn't the API call reached the code in order? The code was working fine in the live server before.. Kindly give advice how I could troubleshoot this issue.. Thank you.

Comment: Hate to make it sound trivial, but if you hit that log, then it is because you did a GET instead of a POST

Comment: Are you 100% sure you are using a POST request?

Comment: I use the same client application and just changed the URL from local to live server; uhm probably I'll have to debug the client app then

Comment: Try to debug using a REST client (like Postman)  just in case to confirm the hunch of everyone :)

Comment: yes, 100% sure, just tested and also marked the solution below

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe it's your nginx if it's on the server. [POST request turns into GET request](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24028719/post-request-turns-into-get-request)

I assumed you tried on your local machine without nginx while the server has one.

Comment: ok, i just checked that the real issue is in my nginx configuration - it converted post to get .. thanks a lot!

Answer (score 1):

seems like in the live server you made a get request, not post.